# Issues aligning elements left and right on same line

Tags: html, css

I have two divs at the moment that I'm wanting to float on left and right sides however they are both kinda sticking to each other and can't seperate them..

### html:

```
<nav>
        <div id="nav_content">
            <div id="home_icon" />
            <div id="search_icon" />
        </div> 
   </nav>
```

So I'm trying to float the home_icon to left and search_icon to right:

### CSS

```
    nav
{
    background:white no-repeat;
    width:75%;
    height:5em;
    margin-left:8em;
}
#nav_content
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#home_icon
{
    background:url(../images/home.png) no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:50%;
    position:relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition:ease-in-out 0.5s;
    margin-left:1em;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

#search_icon
{
    background:url(../images/searchicon.png) no-repeat;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    transition:ease-in-out 0.5s;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;


}
```

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/dnppj2st/ and use </div> to close divs properly and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do

```
<div id="home_icon" />
<div id="search_icon" />
```

in HTML 5. Because it means the same as

```
<div id="home_icon">
<div id="search_icon">
```

which makes the browser think that `#search_icon` is inside `#home_icon`.

So, either set the DocType to XHTML or close the divs properly.

Related Question - [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)
jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9vd01zx5/

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong HTML closing tags

use:

```
<div id="home_icon">Left</div>
<div id="search_icon">Right</div>
```

Remove the text left and right later..